# Java WSDL return string in xml format

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

My web service is returning XML in string format and i am calling it through SOAP-UI.

When execution is successful, SOAP UI will auto enclosed the return result in character data tag as such:

```
<![CDATA[<result>
    <tagA>
        <tagA1 />
        <tagA2 />
        <tagA3 />
    </tagA>
    <tagB>blah</tagB>
    <tagC>blah</tagC>
</result>]]>
```

But when returning error, instead of enclosing result in character data tag, all less than symbol (<) is translated into HTML character, &lt ;

```
&lt;result>
    &lt;error>blah&lt;/error>
&lt;/result>
```

Why this is happening? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your own method to put the `CDATA`-Tag around your xml?
Is this code still executed in case of an exception?